# Brother 2170W toner is stuck after paper was jammed

Tags: printer, toner

While printing paper jammed (I think even 2 sheets), paper stuck and i can't pull it out.
The main problem that the toner is stuck as well!
I can't pull it out even with moderate force!

What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my experience... use more force. those toner carts are PRETTY tough.

If you're uncomfortable with that, you'll have to try to remove as much paper as possible (ripping it out pretty much - use needle nose pliers if you need to) and yank the cart out

Comment: I tried to pull it with almost extreme force( more force will break the plastic holder). when i try to pull the papaer (about 1 cm of it i can reach from both side) i tear it.

Comment: I don't understand how paper can block the toner? maybe it something else?

Comment: you don't mean the toner cart? big HUGE chunk of plastic with the rollers in it?

Comment: yes the  cart, i can't take it out (and yes I release the green lock on the left side and yes i rise it up and pull)

Comment: well, short of dismantling the whole printer, pulling is the best option . there's really not much else that you can do. The paper is between the print roller and another roller at the bottom - if its overthick, it'll jam.

Comment: But what holds the toner tray? the paper? If I decide to use superior force, can I brake it?